# How can I kill a process by name instead of PID, on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill

Sometimes when I try to start Firefox it says "a Firefox process is already running". So I have to do this:

```
jeremy@jeremy-desktop:~$ ps aux | grep firefox
jeremy    7451 25.0 27.4 170536 65680 ?        Sl   22:39   1:18 /usr/lib/firefox-3.0.1/firefox
jeremy    7578  0.0  0.3   3004   768 pts/0    S+   22:44   0:00 grep firefox
jeremy@jeremy-desktop:~$ kill 7451
```

What I'd like is a command that would do all that for me. It would take an input string and `grep` for it (or whatever) in the list of processes, and would kill all the processes in the output:

```
jeremy@jeremy-desktop:~$ killbyname firefox
```

I tried doing it in PHP but `exec('ps aux')` seems to only show processes that have been executed with `exec()` in the PHP script itself (so the only process it shows is itself.)

Comment: When I get the window that says that Firefox already runs I usually just have to wait one second and I can run Firefox again (of course it might not always be the case).

Comment: This is the safest way as JohnB says in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381229/how-to-kill-all-processes-matching-a-name/19733066#19733066

Comment: This is an old question, but could you please change the accepted answer? The one you marked fails with many processes, like those run by the JVM.

Comment: For anyone referencing this topic, in the above comment, Luis is referencing the answer below that touts the `pkill -f "Process name"` command...

Answer (score 734, accepted):

```
pkill firefox
```

More information: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pkill.htm

Comment: Using pgrep to figure out what you're killing before you go around slaying processes is a Good Thing. Especially when using `-f`.

Comment: pkill isnt very friendly. you cant give it names the same way killall takes them.

Comment: `pkill -U <username>` is quite handy.  I have a **Solaris** web server, the actual web server daemon, is setup as a *Service* with it's own user. So specifying by user is a simple / easy way to trigger a restart.

Comment: To force kill:

    pkill -9 firefox

Comment: This works half the times at best. You need at least the `-f` flag for an omnibus solution.

Answer (score 217):

Also possible to use:

```
pkill -f "Process name"
```

For me, it worked up perfectly. It was what I have been looking for.
pkill doesn't work with name without the flag.

When `-f` is set, the full command line is used for pattern matching.

Comment: specially for running something with *wine* the `-f` option is truly needed. e.g. `pkill -f "EvilWindowsServer.exe"`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The first answer fails with many kinds of programmes, e.g. those running on a JVM.

Comment: I had to add the `-f` flag too for killing a background process running a Python script.

Answer (score 74):

You can kill processes by *name* with [`killall <name>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

> **killall** sends a signal to all
>   processes running any of the specified
>   commands. If no signal name is
>   specified, SIGTERM is sent.
>
> Signals can be specified either by
>   name (e.g. **-HUP** or **-SIGHUP** ) or by number (e.g.
>   **-1**) or by option **-s**.
>
> If the command name is not regular
>   expression (option **-r**) and contains a
>   slash (/), processes executing that
>   particular file will be selected for
>   killing, independent of their name.

But if you don't see the process with `ps aux`, you probably won't have the right to kill it ...

Comment: To force terminating a program that is not responding, send KILL instead of TERM: `killall -s KILL firefox`

Answer (score 71):

The easiest way to do is first check you are getting right process IDs with:

```
pgrep -f [part_of_a_command]
```

If the result is as expected. Go with:

```
pkill -f [part_of_a_command]
```

If processes get stuck and are unable to accomplish the request you can use kill.

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -f [part_of_a_command])
```

If you want to be on the safe side and only terminate processes that you initially started add `-u` along with your username

```
pkill -f [part_of_a_command] -u [username]
```

Comment: underrated answer 

Comment: `pkill -f [part_of_a_command]`
didn't work. I used: 

`kill -9 $(pgrep -f "part_of_a_command")`

Comment: pkill only signals all processes that match the criteria given on the command line. Sometimes processes get stuck and are unable to accomplish the request. `kill -9` forces the request and terminates the process.

Comment: good solution, I just added -u [USERNAME] to be on the safe side when I use it on a shared cluster. `pgrep -f [part_of_a_command] -u [username]`

Comment: Thanks @anilbey. I will add this to my post as well

Answer (score 58):

A bit longer alternative:

```
kill `pidof firefox`
```

Comment: pidof firefox | xargs kill -9

Comment: this one works under busybox for your embedded devices :)

Answer (score 37):

**Kill all processes having `snippet` in startup path.** You can kill all apps started from some directory by for putting /directory/ as a snippet. This is quite usefull when you start several components for the same application from the same app directory.

```
ps ax | grep <snippet> | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

* I would prefer pgrep if available

Comment: This is a frequently seen combination of antipatterns. Use a regex which doesn't match itself (or the name of the containing script) and avoid a [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep). `ps ax | awk '/[s]nippet/ { print $1 }' | xargs kill`

Comment: while avoiding useless grep you are not avoiding typos and ability to use the command in automated processes which parameterize the <snippet>

Comment: THIS is indeed the best way to do it !

Comment: Would be great to understand why @tripleee's `[s]` works in terms of not matching the awk process itself?

Comment: Because the regex `[x]y` matches the string `xy` but not vice versa. This is a common FAQ. The link is to a page from more than 20 years ago which explains this in more detail; and this was a recurring question already then.

Comment: You can generate `[s]nippet` from `snippet` easily. Bash has `[${variable:0:1}]${variable:1}` or more portably you can use a parameter substitution `${variable#?}` to pluck off the first character.

Comment: This was the option I needed to use in Git Bash on Windows as the other utils weren't available. Thanks!

Comment: If you use this often and want to define an alias for this then you'll need to make a slight modification to the `awk` part. See here for more info: https://superuser.com/a/696420

Answer (score 28):

Strange, but I haven't seen the solution like this:

```
kill -9 `pidof firefox`
```

it can also kill multiple processes (multiple pids) like:

```
kill -9 `pgrep firefox`
```

I prefer `pidof` since it has single line output:

```
> pgrep firefox
6316
6565
> pidof firefox
6565 6316
```

Comment: When i execute this, i got the error `kill: invalid number 'pidof myprogram'`. What is bad in here?.

Comment: this just saved my life today... I don't want to write more but I am glad I found it here. thanks man.

Comment: Coming late but in case someone else wonders… @Brethlosze you put single ticks, while the command requires backticks.

Comment: Thanks!.. i will be (and i am being) aware of these backticks :)

Comment: You can use `pgrep ssh -d' '` to show the output in one line

Answer (score 25):

Using `killall` command:

```
killall processname
```

Use `-9` or `-KILL` to forcefully kill the program (the options are similar to the `kill` command).

Answer (score 12):

On Mac I could not find the pgrep and pkill neither was killall working so wrote a simple one liner script:-

```
export pid=`ps | grep process_name | awk 'NR==1{print $1}' | cut -d' ' -f1`;kill $pid
```

If there's an easier way of doing this then please share.

Comment: Lol. This is an insane command to such task. Nevermind. Did you call that simple one line? :D

Simple is killall

Comment: @erm3nda :-) Agree. Looking back it looks insane. Can't recollect why killall wasn't working on my mac then.

Comment: This is very useful when you want to kill a certain Java process like "jboss". In that case killall doesn't help.

Answer (score 8):

To kill with grep:

```
kill -9 `pgrep myprocess`
```

Comment: Worked for me. Had a bit of trouble setting up on an `alias` but got it working by escaping the `\`` characters: `alias k = "kill -9 \\`pgrep xyz\\`"`

Answer (score 5):

I normally use the `killall` command.

[Check this link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) for details of this command.

Answer (score 5):

more correct would be:

```
export pid=`ps aux | grep process_name | awk 'NR==1{print $2}' | cut -d' ' -f1`;kill -9 $pid
```

Comment: Why do you `export` a variable which you are only going to use once in the same process?

Answer (score 3):

I was asking myself the same question but the problem with the current answers is that they don't **safe check the processes to be killed** so... it could lead to terrible mistakes :)... especially if **several processes matches the pattern**.

As a disclaimer, I'm not a sh pro and there is certainly room for improvement.

So I wrote a little sh script :

```
#!/bin/sh

killables=$(ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v mykill | grep -v grep)
if [ ! "${killables}" = "" ]
then
  echo "You are going to kill some process:"
  echo "${killables}"
else
  echo "No process with the pattern $1 found."
  return
fi
echo -n "Is it ok?(Y/N)"
read input
if [ "$input" = "Y" ]
then
  for pid in $(echo "${killables}" | awk '{print $2}')
  do
    echo killing $pid "..."
    kill $pid 
    echo $pid killed
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -e myprocessname| awk '{ print $2 }')

Answer (score 2):

If you run GNOME, you can use the system monitor (System->Administration->System Monitor) to kill processes as you would under Windows. KDE will have something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The default `kill` command accepts command names as an alternative to PID. See [kill (1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html#ARGUMENTS). An often occurring trouble is that `bash` provides its own `kill` which accepts job numbers, like `kill %1`, but not command names. This hinders the default command. If the former functionality is more useful to you than the latter, you can disable the `bash` version by calling

`enable -n kill`

For more info see `kill` and `enable` entries in [bash (1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN%20COMMANDS).

Comment: How i reenable the action did by `enable -n kill`?

Comment: @hyprfrcb `enable kill`

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep processname | cut -d' ' -f7 | xargs kill -9 $
```

Answer (score 0):

awk oneliner, which parses the header of `ps` output, so you don't need to care about column numbers (but column names). Support regex. For example, to kill all processes, which executable name (without path) contains word "firefox" try

```
ps -fe | awk 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i=="COMMAND") Ncmd=i; else if ($i=="PID") Npid=i} if (!Ncmd || !Npid) {print "wrong or no header" > "/dev/stderr"; exit} }$Ncmd~"/"name"$"{print "killing "$Ncmd" with PID " $Npid; system("kill "$Npid)}' name=.*firefox.*
```