# How to kill all processes matching a name?

Tags: shell, command-line, kill

Say I want to kill every process containing the word amarok. I can print out the commands I want to execute. But how do I actually make the shell execute them. ie.

```
ps aux | grep -ie amarok | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}'
Output:
kill -9 3052
kill -9 3071
kill -9 3076
kill -9 3077
kill -9 3079
kill -9 3080
kill -9 3082
kill -9 3083
kill -9 3084
kill -9 3085
kill -9 3086
kill -9 3087
kill -9 3088
kill -9 3089
kill -9 4031
```

Comment: Add `| sh -x` after the remainder of your command line?

Comment: never ever use `kill -9` on a process see [process management][1]

  [1]: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryUnix%5Cb%29#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...

Comment: Adding to the above comment that not only is the kill -9 a bad idea but also the fact that you are trying to kill multiple processes via their name. There is nothing unique about the name of a process and hence is a bad candidate for identification.

Comment: Will it kill `amarokx` process too? I pkill vi, it kills  `supervisorctl` which contains `vi' in the word.

Comment: That article on not using `-9` is pretty unhelpful - is there any better information on why people shouldn't use it? It just says "dont, and fire people who use it"; but all I've ever seen everywhere else is that `kill -9 {pid}` is how to kill something...

Comment: from `man kill`: kill -9 sends the SIGKILL signal. This is a `non-catchable, non-ignorable kill`. Meaning that the application will not get to clean up and properly save progress.

Comment: Usually when I want to kill a process, its because its stuck, and its not responding to any other kill commands. The only time I actually use the kill command is if something is horribly frozen and then I force it with -9.

Comment: `kill -9` may result in large amounts of garbage in the filesystem and in memory. Do it enough, and your system will choke.

Answer (score 561, accepted):

From `man 1 pkill`

```
-f     The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.
       When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

Which means, for example, if we see these lines in `ps aux`:

```
apache   24268  0.0  2.6 388152 27116 ?        S    Jun13   0:10 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   24272  0.0  2.6 387944 27104 ?        S    Jun13   0:09 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   24319  0.0  2.6 387884 27316 ?        S    Jun15   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

We can kill them all using the pkill `-f` option:

```
pkill -f httpd
```

Comment: I realize this doesn't adress the subject of this question, but it does demonstrate an alternate, and shorter, method of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: For extra strength, add `-9` to the end!

Comment: Will it kill `httpdx` process too? I pkill vi, it kills  `supervisorctl` which contains `vi' in the word.

Comment: Awesome - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: For case-insensitive matches use `-i`, like `pkill -fi wine`. To verify before and after, use `ps uax | grep -i wine`.

Comment: can use the following (works on CentOS): ps -ef | grep -i '<process_name>' | grep -iv grep | awk '{print $2}' | tr "\n" " "

Answer (score 270):

```
ps aux | grep -ie amarok | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

xargs(1): xargs -- construct argument list(s) and execute utility.  Helpful when you want to pipe in arguments to something like `kill` or `ls` or so on.

Comment: Points for mentioning xargs - all this pgrep / pkill stuff is all very well, but xargs is a general purpose tool, and standard on every linux/unix.

Comment: "kill: No such process"

Comment: Cerin that's because it's trying to kill the grep process as well, which already finished. It should be fine.

Comment: There's a little trick to avoiding capturing the grep process:  ps aux | grep -ie [a]marok | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Comment: you can also add another grep call to filter out grep (I find this easier to read/remember) `ps aux | grep -ie amarok | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`  (`grep -v` stands for `grep --invert`)

Comment: No no no, all of that is [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).  You want `ps aux | awk '/amarok/ { print $2 }' | xargs kill` (mostly without the `-9` as suggested elsewhere, and also on the linked page).

Comment: Take care, the process ids (pids) are not always located in the second column (which is used in the awk code by using `$2`), but in the first column. Hence, use `$1`. This holds for git-bash on Windows for example.

Comment: won't kill certain orphaned processes

Answer (score 64):

use `pgrep`

```
kill -9 $(pgrep amarok)
```

Comment: even eleganter: `pkill -9 amarok`

Comment: pkill handles the "every process containing the word <word>" part natively without creating more pipes or processes. See the -f option for full process name searching to eliminate the need for pgrep.

Comment: Beware that pkill by default allows partial matching on process names. This command would also kill amarok2 if it existed. Use -x or -f if you want to specify exact names.

Comment: It will fail if the are not matches for pgrep

Comment: for full name match use `kill -9 $(pgrep -f amarok)`

Answer (score 40):

**The safe way to do this is:**

```
pkill -f amarok
```

Comment: To add to this, I added the `-l` flag. I actually just aliased `pkill` to `pkill -fl` so I can run something like `pkill jboss` and it will spit out the process that it just killed.

Comment: Will it kill `amarokx` process too? I pkill vi, it kills  `supervisorctl` which contains `vi' in the word.

Comment: How is this different from the top (Tim's) answer? Just matches the example name, otherwise looks identical? @ndland `pkill: invalid option -- 'l'` - pkill from procps-ng 3.3.12

Answer (score 21):

I think this command killall is exactly what you need.
The command is described as "kill processes by name".It's easy to use.For example

```
killall chrome
```

This command will kill all process of Chrome.Here is a link about killall command

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_killall.htm

Hope this command could help you.

Comment: This only matches by name, not full command line. Definitely not the same as searching `ps aux`'s output

Answer (score 17):

pkill -x matches the process name exactly.

```
pkill -x amarok
```

pkill -f is similar but allows a regular expression pattern.

Note that pkill  with no other parameters (e.g. -x, -f) will allow partial matches on process names. So "pkill amarok" would kill amarok, amarokBanana, bananaamarok, etc.

I wish -x was the default behavior!

Comment: Will it kill `amarokx` process too? I pkill vi, it kills  `supervisorctl` which contains `vi' in the word.

Comment: @Gank, yes, any process name with "amarok" in it somewhere.

Comment: How to only kill amarok instead of amarokx?

Comment: @Gank,-x flag. pkill -x amarok

Comment: Why isn't it the default. Really strange. I killed too many processes, because I did not use `-x` :|

Answer (score 6):

try `` kill -s 9 `ps -ef |grep "Nov 11" |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` ``  To kill processes of November 11
or
`` kill -s 9 `ps -ef |grep amarok|grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` `` 
To kill processes that contain the word amarok

Answer (score 4):

If you want to execute the output of a command, you can put it inside `$(...)`, however for your specific task take a look at the `killall` and `pkill` commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can also evaluate your output as a sub-process, by surrounding everything with back ticks or with putting it inside $():

```
`ps aux | grep -ie amarok | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}'`

 $(ps aux | grep -ie amarok | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cygwin or some minimal shell that lacks `killall` you can just use this script:

### killall.sh - Kill by process name.

```
#/bin/bash
ps -W | grep "$1" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill --
```

### Usage:

```
$ killall <process name>
```

Comment: I'm getting `kill: invalid argument f`

Comment: Try replacing -f with --

Comment: `ps aux | grep "$1" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill --` works for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the commands to executable file, setting +x permission and then executing?

```
ps aux | grep -ie amarok | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}' > pk;chmod +x pk;./pk;rm pk
```