# Kill list of processes

Tags: macos

Hi Guys I need to kill all processes in a session but only from an user, not all.

Like user1, find all PIDs in them and print them like

120,451,487,455,... then exclude some I want for example I want 120 and 451 to not be killed but the rest yes.

I can do kill -9 PID this will kill the PID, but I am not sure how to kill all of them or find them from the user

Comment: This looks to be same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381229/how-to-kill-all-processes-matching-a-name

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell you can do whatever you want.Please visit the following web page.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177004.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Who on Earth would willingly install **Microsoft Powershell** on a Mac? Surely there must be some mistake?

Comment: This link with powershell download and install to Mac.
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell