# Killing processes SHELL

Tags: shell, unix, process, kill

This command `ps -ef | grep php` returns a list of processes

I want to kill in one command or with a shell script all those processes

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to kill all commands with a given name is to use [`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall):

```
killall php
```

Note, this only sends an interrupt signal. This should be enough if the processes are behaving. If they're not dying from that, you can forcibly kill  them using

```
killall -9 php
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do this is to use `xargs` as in `ps -ef | grep php | xargs kill`, but there are several ways to do this.

- `ps -ef` lists all processes and then you use `grep` to pick a few lines that mention "php". This means that also commands that have "php" as part of their command line will match, and be killed. If you really want to match the command (and not the arguments as well), it is probably better to use `pgrep php`.
- You can use a shell backtick to provide the output of a command as arguments to another command, as in

  kill `pgrep php`
- If you want to kill processes only, there is a command `pkill` that matches a pattern to the command. This can not be used if you want to do something else with the processes though. This means that if you want to kill all processes where the command contain "php", you can do this using `pkill php`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find its pid (it's on the first column `ps` prints) and use the `kill` command to forcibly kill it:

```
kill -9 <pid you found>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `xargs`:

```
ps -ef | grep php | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

`grep -v grep` is exclude the command itself and `awk` gives the list of PIDs which are then passed `kill` command.

Comment: The trick to avoid `ps | grep php | grep -v grep` is `ps | grep '[p]hp'`

Comment: @glennjackman I know `killall` is better. But killing by name is different than killing all processes that has `php`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pkill php`. More on this topic in this similar question: [How can I kill a process by name instead of PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160924/how-can-i-kill-a-process-by-name-instead-of-pid)