# Trying to kill process by shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to kill process through shell scripting it is giving me error. Here is what i tried so far:

When i try to kill memcache it give me error like "kill: No such process" , i used below command:

```
ps -ef | grep "memcache" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill;
```

or if try like below:

```
kill -9 $(pidof memcache)
```

i get error like below:": arguments must be process or job IDs"

When i run directly on command prompt process is running:

```
ring@ubuntu:~/parasol$ ps aux | grep memcache     
memcache   873  0.0  0.0 323220  1188 ?        Sl   22:56   0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
ring      1714  0.0  0.0   9384   920 pts/0    S+   23:45   0:00 grep --color=auto memcache
```

I reff to https://askubuntu.com/questions/239923/shell-script-to-9-kill-based-on-name
AND
[Shell script to capture Process ID and kill it if exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910087/shell-script-to-capture-process-id-and-kill-it-if-exist)

My Ubuntu Version:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.2 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

Comment: What is result if `pidof memcache` or `ps -ef | grep "memcache" | awk '{print $2}'`? Looks ok.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/160926/2231893

Comment: pidof memcache does not give anything, no error no id.

Comment: Acutally `ps -ef | grep memcache` will give two lines.. 

so you can go this way `ps -ef | grep memcache | grep -v "grep" |  awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill;`

Comment: @Ashish: it gives error ": No such file or directory", 

but when i run   ps -ef | grep memcache | grep -v "grep" it gives only one process. Problem with awk...

Comment: I had linux mint using its GUI so there is process gnome terminal 

i executed `ps -ef  | grep gnome-terminal | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'` and got  2803 which is the PID

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acutally

```
ps -ef | grep memcache
```

will give two lines..

so you can go this way

```
ps -ef | grep memcache | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill;
```

This can get you exact one PID

if I has to do I would break it in 2 lines in start

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=`ps -ef | grep memcache | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $PID
#to check PID is right
kill -9 $PID
```

save it in scrip files say test.sh

then on terminal

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

then

```
./test.sh
```

Comment: it give error at line where i am storing PID as
line 3: PID: command not found

Comment: I am getting pid but not able to store in variable.

Comment: what is o/p `ps -ef | grep memcache | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: it gives me process id.

Comment: you make a script with say test.sh with  copy above lines in it and run script

Comment: copied now, it echo pid. But while killing it gives

ring@ubuntu:~/parasol$ bash my_test_batch.sh 
873
: arguments must be process or job IDs
ring@ubuntu:~/parasol$

Comment: Please try it on some other process and check

Comment: Gaaa, [useless uses of `grep`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) galore! You mean `ps -ef | awk '/[m]emcache/{print$2}'`.

Comment: useless uses of `ps`, `grep` and `awk` galore! This can be replaced by `pkill -f -9 memcache`

Answer (score 3):

You can use these commands:
`pkill memcached` 
or
`pgrep memcached | xargs kill -9`
or
`killall memcached`.

pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi If you not use the parameter `-9`, is it work?

Comment: without -9 it give error "kill: Operation not permitted
my_test_batch.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found"

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Sorry i cann't help you. What the version of your linux? The other two commands work or not?

Comment: Thanks BlackMamba for your time and efforts.

Comment: The error messages seem to indicate that you somehow get a DOS carriage return in there somewhere. Irrespective of that, this is the Right Answer. +1

Comment: @tripleee regardless of the carriage return issue, this answer is still incorrect, i.e. it won't catch memcached.

Answer (score 2):

Your first command might be killing itself before having  chance to kill the target processes.

For a reliable way, run `pkill /usr/bin/memcached` or `pkill -9 /usr/bin/memcached` although the latter is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

For the first command, you see that there are *two* processes that matches the pattern you grep for. The actual `memcached` process and your `grep` process. That is probably the reason for the error of the first command line.

Try narrowing the search down, for example by grepping for e.g. `"^memcache.*/usr/bin/memcached"`.

---

The problem with the second error is that you're calling `pidof` with the *username* instead of the process name, so the command is essentially `kill -9` without any process id. Try instead e.g. `pidof memcached` to get the process id of the correct process.

Comment: I try like this:
sudo ps -ef | grep ^memcache.*/usr/bin/memcached | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill;

giving error:
kill: Operation not permitted
my_test_batch.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Can you try with the quotes around the `grep` regex?

Comment: with quotes it give error ": No such file or directory". But i have memcached directory in usr/bin/

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> ps -ef | grep "memcache" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill; 
> PID=`ps -ef | grep memcache | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
> #...
> ```

First, you could use `cut` instead of `awk` in this case. No need to use a tank to kill a fly ;)

Then, why is it necessary to brutally kill memcache? You have a daemon to stop it :

```
/etc/init.d/memcached stop
service memcached stop
```

Answer (score -2):

if your application does have port running you can use this

```
lsof -t -i :port# | xargs kill -9
```