# Kill a Running Process by its Name

Tags: linux, arm, kill

When running a [kill command by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160924/how-can-i-kill-a-process-by-name-instead-of-pid) in a Linux RT ARM version:

```
kill -9 'pidof program'
```

I have the error

```
kill: invalid number 'pidof myprogram'
```

what is wrong in here? how can i know which version of `kill`?

Comment: The source you copied that line from uses backquotes (left of `1` on my keyboard), not normal apostrophes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong quote `'`, use `` ` `` instead.

```
kill -9 `pidof program`
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use command 'pkill'

```
pkill program

pkill -9 program
```