# Create Alias to execute kill of app in Mac

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to create an alias in my .bash_profile so if I run it it will kill any app that I choose.

What I've done:

```
alias terminate='ps -ax | grep '
```

If I run terminate App, returns list of App ID, so then I do kill + App ID and it's done.

Now, if that App has many ID's it's a pain in the ass to have to do kill + ID for each ID.

Apparently, if I do `kill -9 $(ps -ax | grep App)`, it kills the entire App.
(What I do is `kill -9 $(terminate App)`)

Now I want to create another alias, as `fullkill`, so if I run `fullkill App` it would do the same.

What I've tried:

```
alias fullkill='kill -9 $(ps -ax | grep )'
```

Run:

```
fullkill App
```

Returns

```
- bash: kill: App: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

Comment: `kill "$(pgrep "name")"` or if you want to kill some scripts `kill "$(pgrep -f "name")"` or even better `pkill "name"`

Comment: You could use `pkill` [Docs](https://ss64.com/osx/pkill.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I kill a process by name instead of PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160924/how-can-i-kill-a-process-by-name-instead-of-pid) in combination with [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/)

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` routinely. You should send trappable signal like 15 or 2, and only then if the program is too buggy or too hung escalate to the thermonuclear option.