# Is there a way, with C in linux, to close another application?

Tags: c, linux

I would like to make a program that can block some programs from being opened, or stop them after they've started. I can only code in C and would also like to add a GUI, so I cannot use bash and kill. Is there a way to close another program from C?

I want to basically create a "time-delay" so I cannot start minecraft during the school day.

I would like to keep the code as efficient as possible, and have not been able to find any tools like a service that would efficiently close apps or block them from starting in the first place.

Comment: [kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) is available as a C API.

Comment: Why does having a GUI prevent you from using bash and kill?

Comment: I want to stop another program, not a child process.

Comment: I can't find a question about killing in general, but the answer is the same. Ignore the "by the parent process" part. The other questions I'm seeing are about killing from shell scripts, or about more advanced killing (e.g. an entire tree of processes).

Comment: Thanks, is there an equivalent so I can use the name instead of the PID?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. See also: [ask]

Comment: I have looked in to several things that would allow me to create a service, however the serveice denies permission for even the root user.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share what you've tried.

Comment: I also want to ensure the program induces the least drag on my PC, and so for all of the other things I want to use C.

Comment: You really don't need to write code for this sort of thing. You could for example only allow a certain login access to the minecraft app using Linux permissions. Then you can use techniques such as [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150705/restrict-the-times-a-user-is-allowed-to-log-in) to prevent login for that account during certain times.

Comment: FYI there's no need to use C. No language, whether that's Bash or Python or anything else, will have any noticeable CPU load. Unless you just want to sharpen your C skills it's not buying you anything except unnecessary complexity. It's the wrong tool for the job, IMO.

Comment: I will try in bash, however I do still need to be able to use the computer, just block specific applications.

Comment: @Joshua One of the answers [recommends `pkill -f`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820938/68587), which is perfect for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we want to do is locate the process and `kill()` it. It's not so hard. It's just very long because the executable isn't `minecraft`, it's `java`, so we look for the `.jar` file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void kill_minecraft()
{
    char buf[8192];
    DIR *dir = opendir("/proc");
    struct dirent *dirent;
    while ((dirent = readdir(dir)))
    {
        pid_t pid = atol(dirent->d_name);
        if (pid > 0)
        {
            sprintf(buf, "/proc/%s/cmdline", dirent->d_name);
            FILE *in = fopen(buf, "r");
            if (in)
            {
                size_t nmem = fread(buf, 1, 8192, in);
                fclose(in);
                buf[8192] = 0;
                // Recognize minecraft's jar in the command line
                if (nmem > 0 && (char *ptr = (char*)memmem(buf, "minecraft/versions/", nmem)))
                {
                     char *p1 = (char*)strstr(ptr, ":");
                     char *p2 = (char*)strstr(ptr, ".jar");
                     if (p2 && (!p1 || p1 > p2))
                     {
                         // Match! Goodbye!
                         kill(pid, 9);
                     }
                }
                fclose(in);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Whew. Let's break this down. This function iterates over all running processes and reads in its command line. Once having done so, it checks the command line for minecraft's pattern; that is having a command line argument of minecraft/versions/something/something.jar. In java, the jar arguments are glommed together separated by `:` characters, so it handles that. On getting a match, it calls `kill`.

Scheduling this function is left as an exercise for the reader. See `time()` and `sleep()` functions. As for running it, the lazy way is to stick a call to it into `/etc/rc.local`.

You can do this with `pkill -f` in a loop, but that regex is hard to write and I don't want to figure it out.

Comment: This gives an absurd amount of errors with GCC, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Grant: Probably not. It hasn't been anywhere near a compiler yet and is probably full of typos.

Comment: Does it require the MC directory being home/.minecraft?

Comment: I have to go for the night, sorry. I will check back tomorrow.

Comment: @Grant: Nope! Home directory doesn't matter.